# Linux C TCP Handshake with Raw Socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I read all questions on stackoverflow with this problem but it's not solved my problem. I need to do a TCP handshake with Raw Sockets (C, Linux). I know if my source ip will be random I will can't get reply. I need to only send a packet to the server and server need to receive it and send reply to a source ip.

(https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/raw-socket-4175419375/
or
[Linux C raw socket TCP handsake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630216/linux-c-raw-socket-tcp-handsake))

I using this code to solve this problem. So, has anyone a normal tcp checksum with this code?

Comment: Are you asking about how to make a TCP three-way handshake? Or how to create a TCP packet checksum function? Or something else to do with the random addresses?

Comment: And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, of course I interested how to make a TCP three-way handshake or create a TCP packet checksum but it's not solve my problem. I need to do TCP Handshake with RAW SOCKETS not default SOCK_STREAM.

Comment: On TCP checksums: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Checksum_computation